# WCF Rest Service to Take a list of Json Objects as parameter

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf, oracle12c

I am trying to insert a list of holidays into a Holiday Table inside my Oracle 12c DB using WCF Rest services. When I am running my service, I am not getting an error, but the data is not being inserted when I run the service. 
I believe there is an issue with my cmdStr and UpdateHoliday() . Any help is appreciated much. Thanks.

IService1.cs

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract()]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateHoliday", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    void UpdateHoliday(List<Holiday> Holidays);
}


[DataContract]
public class Holiday
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string HOLIDAY { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

    public List<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
}

public class ListofHoliday
{
    [DataMember]
    List<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
}
```

Service1.cs

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void UpdateHoliday(List<Holiday> Holidays)
    {
        List<ListofHoliday> firstStringList = new List<ListofHoliday>();
        string cmdStr = String.Format("INSERT INTO HOLIDAY (HOLIDAY, Description)" +
                                   " VALUES('HOLIDAY','Description')");

        foreach (var item in firstStringList)
        {
            (new DbHelper()).SqlExecute(cmdStr);
        }
    }


}
```

DbHelper.cs

```
 class DbHelper
    {
        private static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }

        public DataTable GetResultSet(string sql)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, ConnectionString))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            return dt;
        }

        public void SqlExecute(string sql)
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, new OracleConnection(ConnectionString)))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

I finally was able to found a way to make it work. The changes are below:
Service1.cs

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void UpdateHoliday(List<Holiday> Holidays)
    {
        if (Holidays == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Holidays");

        foreach (var item in Holidays)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("INSERT INTO HOLIDAY (HOLIDAY, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ");
            sb.AppendFormat("( '{0}', '{1}')",
                item.HOLIDAY, item.DESCRIPTION);
            //sb.AppendFormat(";");
            (new DbHelper()).SqlExecute(sb.ToString());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Any error indicators?

Comment: I do not get any error at all. After sending my Json list of objects, the only thing I get is " The response was empty". Which is expected if it worked. :|

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do in your service operation loop, however, with that code, nothing will ever get inserted. You are creating an empty list and then iterating over it and inserting the same values with each iteration. Your for loop will break as soon as the empty list gets evaluated. Is that what you expected?

Comment: nope that is not what I intended to do. Thank you for pointing it out. What I want to do is receive a list of objects and insert it in my table "HOLIDAY". I want my method to fetch those input parameters and insert them into the Holiday table. Do you have any advice for me to make the list not empty and insert the data from the list of objects. I posted an updated code for UpdateHoliday() below. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: public void UpdateHoliday(List<Holiday> Holidays)
        {
            
            string cmdStr = String.Format("INSERT INTO HOLIDAY (HOLIDAY, Description)" +
                                       " VALUES('{0}', '{1}')");

            foreach (var item in Holidays)
            {
                (new DbHelper()).SqlExecute(cmdStr);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Howa about trying out this code in your service operation. If the code below works then you still have some work to do in order to get your DBHelper to accept a command with parameters.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void UpdateHoliday(List<Holiday> Holidays)
    {
        if(Holidays==null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("Holidays");

        string cmdStr = String.Format("INSERT INTO HOLIDAY (HOLIDAY, Description)" +
                                   " VALUES('HOLIDAY','Description')");

        foreach (var item in Holidays)
        {
            (new DbHelper()).SqlExecute(cmdStr);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: if(Holiday==null) part is giving me an error : 'Holiday is a type which is not valid in the given context'. Another issue is I want the values (''HOLIDAY','Description')  to be from the parameter input.

Comment: It should be (Holidays==null), I update the answer. As for the parameters, there is a good way to cleanse inline sql  strings using parameters. It has been eons since I have used inline so I will have to look up how to parameterize the SqlCommand.

Comment: I found an online reference for you --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much Ross, your help saved my day! I am checking the reference out !